# Can't add two merge regions in POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to add two merge regions in one row like this:

```
// Cell Range Address
CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress_1 = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 3, 6);
CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress_2 = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 7,9);

// Creating cells
cell = row.createCell(3); // 1
cell.setCellStyle(headingStyle);
cell.setCellValue("CoLUMN 1");

cell = row.createCell(4); // 2
cell.setCellStyle(headingStyle);
cell.setCellValue("COLUMN 2");
```

The first column is merged and "COLUMN 1" is displayed. The second column is merged but the text is NOT displayed !

Am I doing it wrong or is this a bug? I'm using Apache POI 3.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not correctly displaying "COLUMN 2".  You are creating the two cell values and presumably calling `addMergedRegion` to merge cells later.  But when a merged region is present, it doesn't affect the contents of the cells it merges.

Your first merged region (0, 0, 3, 6) represents cells 3 through 6 in the first row (D1:G1), which covers both of your created cells.  Excel will only display the contents of the upper-left cell in a merged region, so only "COLUMN 1" is displayed.  "COLUMN 2" doesn't get shifted out of the way.  The content is there, but the merged region hides it when viewed in Excel.

Your second merged region (0, 0, 7, 9) represents cells 7 through 9 in the first row (H1:J1), but no content is there, given the code you have provided.

I suspect that you want "COLUMN 1" in the first merged region and "COLUMN 2" in the second merged region.  The text "COLUMN 1" is already in the first merged region correctly.  You can simply change the column index of the second cell to 7.

```
cell = row.createCell(7); // 2
```